# value from php into stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

this is my php code

```
<?php
$code='1,2,3';
$this->db->query("CALL SP_db(\"$code\"));
?>
```

if i `var_dump($code)` i get this `string(5) "1,2,3"`

and this my stored procedure code

```
CREATE DEFINER=`test`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SP_db`(v_company varchar(10))

begin

select * from blabla where company_id in (v_company);
.
.
.
```

i use this code to insert some value into table
the problem if i use this code,where i get v_company from php its not working

but if i try to fill the value it works

```
CREATE DEFINER=`test`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SP_db`(v_company varchar(10))

    begin

    select * from blabla where company_id in (1,2,3);
```

but the value being sent by php is received by stored procedures,
i try to save v_company value into table to make sure and it work

because the value from php entered into the table

so can someone tell where the code is wrong

Comment: Try to use PDO http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php Example 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass '1,2,3' to your procedure, you get a string, and your query becomes

```
select * from blabla where company_id in ('1,2,3');
```

not

```
select * from blabla where company_id in (1,2,3);
```

You can use `find_in_set` insted of `in`

```
select * from blabla where find_in_set(company_id, v_company);
```

but it will not use index so well, as `in` does;

Comment: yupp i think like that too,but i don't know how to explain it.......and its works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `"`.

```
$this->db->query("CALL SP_db(\"$code\") ");
```

Or try this

```
$this->db->query("CALL SP_db('".$code."') ");
```